# Counting and numbering inside of a file?

Tags: java

I'm not even sure if i asked that correctly, basically what i want to do is: 1. input a java file 2. have it count and number the open brackets "{", and count down and number the closed brackets "}" so for programs, it would be easier to match brackets and you'd be able to see which open brackets correspond to which close brackets, and for close brackets at the end without an open bracket, give them a 0. For example if the input was something like
blah{ blah{ blah{ blah} blah} blah} } }
it would become
blah{1 blah{2 blah{3 blah}3 blah}2 blah}1 }0 }0
So far all my program does is check for an input file in the console line, if there is none then it prompts the user to enter the file name. The way it is now, all it does is number every "{" with a 0, and now I'm stuck. What can/should I do from this point?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.BufferedReader;


public class BracketCount
{

    public static void main(String args[ ]) throws IOException
    {  

        File fileName;                                                                 
        if (0 <  args.length)                                                                    
        {
        {
            try 
            { 
                File inputFile = new File(args[0]);                                                      
                Scanner in=new Scanner(inputFile);                                      
            }
            catch(IOException exc)   
            {
                System.out.println("File not found");  
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        try 
        {   
          File inputFile2;
            Scanner console=new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("No file in command line, please enter the file: ");
            String fileName2=console.next();
            inputFile2=new File(fileName2);

        }  
        catch(IOException exc)   
        {  
            System.out.println("File not found");   
        }  
    }
}

}
```

Comment: First of all.. A nice question. But the program makes little sense to me. The while loop does nothing. I think you need to correct the syntax first

Comment: Those brackets.......

Comment: There are multiple errors in the code you've provided. Are you using an IDE?

Comment: Correct indentation is not there to look pretty, it's to help you programming by making a sense of what you're doing.

Comment: Your `main` method makes references to `printHeading()` and `text`, neither of which exist. What do you intend them to be?

Comment: @user2921899 I recommend using Eclipse, it's free and one of the best out there.

Comment: i have a printHeading() method, it just prints my name so i didn't paste that part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this

```
// boolean to detect fist closing bracket
boolean firstClose = false;

int count = 0;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while(input.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = input.nextLine();           // get one line
    String newLine = "";                      // start newLine with 0 chars
    for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) { // loop through chars in line
        char ch = line.charAt(i);
        if (ch == '{') {                      // if current char = '{'
            newLine += ch;                    // add '{' to newLine
            count++;                          // increase count
            newLine += count;

            firstClose = true;

        } else if (ch == '}') {    
            if (firstClose) {
                newLine += ch;
                newLine += count;
            } else {
                newLine += ch;                   
                count--;                          
                newLine += count;
                firstClose = false; 
            }              
        } else {
            newLine += ch;                    // else add char to newLine
        }
    }
    sb.append(newLine);                       // append newline to StringBuilder
    sb.append("\n");                          // append a next line char
}

PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file);   
writer.print(sb.toString());                  // print the entire StringBuiler to file.
                                              // This this completely overwrite the
                                              // original file
```

Comment: could i just use System.out.println(sb) to print to console rather than overwrite the file being read?

Comment: Yea, I don't wee why not.

Comment: It's very close! I've tried changing it a bit and can't figure it out, but this doesn't correspond the numbers correctly, it should be {1 {2 {3,   }3 }2 }1, but it's {1 {2 {3 , }2 }1 }0

Comment: I edited it. I added a `boolean` to check whether the closing bracket is the first.  If it is, add the current count. If not, decrease count then add count. That should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you do this :

```
StringBuilder(text);
```

The variable `count` is set to 0. Move this line of code and declare `count` at class level :

```
int count = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be better to scan the file, one character at a time, and whenever you see a '{', insert your counter & then increment it, but whenever you see a '}', decrement your counter and then insert it?  Otherwise, the tags won't match up.  (And even doing this, you'll get into trouble with curly braces inside of string and/or comments.)